# Como inserir uma div em cima da outra?

Tags: html, css, html5, jsp

Estou tentando inserir uma div com o nome em cima da principal, estou criando um painel de monitoramento de metas, onde o canal vem no cabeçalho e a porcentagem realizada será a central, conforme exemplo da foto, mas ao executar meu código, o mesmo não está dando certo, conforme código em exemplo, pode ser algum detalhe que esteja passando despercebido.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -50;
  padding: 0;
}

.jumbo {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/300);
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0px 160px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: right;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.box {
  width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  height: 10rem;
  margin: 1.0em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.p1,
.p2,
.p3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

.p1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: right;
}

.
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>[![Exemplo como o Painel deve ficar][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso sugiro `position:absolute` mesmo, vai ficar como no exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -50;
  padding: 0;
}

.jumbo {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/300);
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0px 160px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: right;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.box {
  width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  height: 10rem;
  margin: 1.0em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.p1,
.p2,
.p3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

.p1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: right;
}

.p2 {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hugo, postei uma imagem de como deve ficar, o nome deve ficar na posição de cima, no cabeçalho.

Comment: @GabrielPaixãoJustino cara é só editar o top/right/left/bottom da classe .p2 para colocar esse elemento no canto que quiser... já editei a resposta